# Chromedriver Crashing on Some Websites

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, dockerfile

I am getting an error on some websites with Chromedriver, but I am having a hard time determining the root cause. The exception is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.88)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'f5126f71f9be', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.39-linuxkit', java.version: '15.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 87.0.4280.88, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 87.0.4280.88 (89e2380a3e36c..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.boI6UV}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:34003}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 39eef34c2a7ceb4b74f515d88945643c
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:277) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at com.example.flockta.FlocktaApplication.hello(FlocktaApplication.java:76) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    ...
```

My code is:

```
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            LOGGER.error("Just created ChromeDriver");
            chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);
            List<String> arguments = new LinkedList<>();
            arguments.add("--disable-extensions");
            arguments.add("--headless");
            arguments.add("--disable-gpu");
            arguments.add("--no-sandbox");

            arguments.add("--no-sandbox");
            arguments.add("--incognito");
            arguments.add("--disable-application-cache");
            chromeOptions.addArguments(arguments);
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
            String websiteAddress = "https://www.exploratorium.edu/";
            driver.get(websiteAddress);
```

My Docker file is:

```
ARG CHROME_VERSION=87.0.4280.88-1
ADD google-chrome.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
RUN microdnf install -y google-chrome-stable-$CHROME_VERSION \
    && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

## ChromeDriver

ARG CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=87.0.4280.88
RUN microdnf install -y unzip \
    && curl -s -o /tmp/chromedriver.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /opt \
    && rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip \
    && mv /opt/chromedriver /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && chmod 755 /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && ln -s /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

Note that per https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.88/notes.txt it supports "Supports Chrome version 87" so I think that part is fine.

My pom.xml has:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out - I needed to add `arguments.add("--disable-dev-shm-usage");`

Comment: Im already adding the above arg. Still im getting the error. Did you find anything else?